# How to open a dialog box in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am creating a online exam web application in asp.net, i want to open a conformation message box or alert message box on button clicking when user submit the test or fill  user information and other task?

Comment: You'll have to use javascript for that. Also, you might want to accept some questions as you'll be more likely to get answers.

Comment: You have asked 9 questions and not accepted one. Maybe work on that first.

Comment: You may want to have a look at the [ConfirmButtonExtender](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/ConfirmButton/ConfirmButton.aspx) available in the AJAX Control Toolkit.

Answer (score 1):

you can just plain javascript like this for an alert on the button: onclick="alert('hello')"

- or for anything fancy I would seriously consider using jQuery dialogs for it. You define the content of the dialog in a hidden div on the page and use a script to attach the dialog to the div by id. Have a look at

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog

Answer (score 0):

you can use `alert(message)` function through javascript to show any message

Answer (score 0):

`alert(message)` or `confirm(message)` are useful javascript functions. Alert just shows the user a message, whereas confirm displays a confirmation box and allows you to get a boolean value back from the user.